# Other tools like Split Features

Tags: qgis, splitting

I want this layer...

[image]

to have the same division/cut/split like this..

[image]

I tried the Split Features tool but this software (qgis 2.16.0) would hang then eventually force close.

Any method/tool that you can suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming screenshot one is a vector, try using Union. Tool description below.

Union - This algorithm creates a layer containing all the features from both input layers. In the case of polygon layers, separate features are created for overlapping and non-overlapping features. The attribute table of the union layer contains attribute values from the respective input layer for non-overlapping features, and attribute values from both input layers for overlapping features.